# How to subtract two datestr in matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime, time

I have a dataset of many samples. Each sample contains start and end time, each taken with datestr(now).

e.g.

```
sample.tstart = datestr(now)
%%Some job is running
sample.tend = datestr(now)
```

how do I subtract the times to evaluate the elapsed time for the job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could convert to a [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html?refresh=true):

```
tdiff = datenum(sample.tend) - datenum(sample.tstart)
```

remebering that as [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html?refresh=true) say:

> A serial date number represents the whole and fractional number of
>   days from a fixed, preset date (January 0, 0000).

so `tdiff` will be in units of days which is then simple to covert to hours or seconds or whatever you're after. For example to covert to seconds:

```
SecondsPerDay = 24*60*60;
tdiffs = tdiff*SecondsPerDay;
```

Comment: Thanks! Stackoverflow would let me accept the answer in a few minutes